# Neo4j adding relationship sometimes very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database with 9832 persons, 172,908 houses and have to add 456,219 relations with additional attributes. I do this with the following query:

```
MATCH (p:Person { uid: { p_uid } }), (h:House { uid: { h_uid } })
MERGE (p)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(h)
ON MATCH SET r.housing_weight = {housing_weight}
ON CREATE SET r.housing_weight = {housing_weight}
```

Thousands of those queries get executed in a second, but then every few thousand queries there's one that takes longer (5-60 seconds), so the execution is drastically slowed down.
There are indices on `p_uid` and `h_uid`, so the match shouldn't be a problem.
I noticed that the slow execution appears at persons that are connected to a lot of houses.

I use the Neo4j 3.0.1 Enterprise Version and execution of the cypher queries is done with the Java Driver 1.0.4.
The Neo4j logs don't really print out any information. Is there a way to track down why the execution is that slow sometimes? Or does anybody already have clues why this is happening?

Comment: You could activate the GC logs (see `dbms.logs.gc.enabled`) to see if it's not the consequence of GC pauses. Side note: shouldn't the `ON MATCH` part add `{housing_weight}` to `r.housing_weight`? `ON MATCH` and `ON CREATE` do the same thing currently.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. There was only regular output, GC pauses are super short.
To your side note: the new housing_weight is calculated in the code, so it's fine.